# Having phpUnit debug configuration to test the current file in phpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, phpunit, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I like to have a debug configuration, that allows me to test the current file.
In every project it is the same, so I like to put variables in these fields:

[image: Debug Config]

So when I am within a test I like to click "Debug" and it runs `phpunit /my/current/test.php` using the given phpunit config.

How to do that?

Comment: You cannot configure this for ALL projects .. but you can configure this for CURRENT project. Do as you do -- configure the Defaults .. and then use context menu in Editor and choose Run (or Debug) -- make sure that you are choosing correct entry (better wording: entry of correct type). Temp Run/Debug config will be created using these defaults.

Comment: that's the one. thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Choose "Run" > "Edit configurations".
- Open "Defaults" and choose the scenario you want
- Place some default stuff there

Run a test using CTRL+SHIFT+F10 (in Ubuntu Gnome).
It will use the default setup on the current focues file.

Answer (score -1):

[phpStorm](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Creating+PHPUnit+Tests+in+PhpStorm) details , you can try it

Comment: It describes how to create a test-class, doesn't it? I am searching for a debug configuration in phpStorm. See the screen above where I marked the things I like to have as variables / dynamical.